"Cannot Focus a Disabled or Invisible Window" error when docking forms in Delphi 12
I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.  I have an application that has a panel on the main form. I have a button that creates a second form.  The panel on the main form has DockingSite set to True.
The second form has a button and an edit box. When you click the button it sets the ActiveControl := Edit1;
When I click the button on the main form, it creates the second form and shows it.  I can now click the button on the second form and focus is set to Edit1. However, if I add a line of code to the main form button that states ManualDock(Panel1) then when I click the button on the second form I get an error:

Cannot Focus a Disabled or Invisible Window

This is the behaviour I would expect to see if I set the Parent of the second form to Panel1.
Does docking a form do essentially the same thing?
Doing this causes the error:
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fm : TForm;
begin
  fm := TForm2.Create(Self);
  fm.ManualDock(Panel1);
  fm.Show;
end;

Commenting out like so and ActiveControl works:
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fm : TForm;
begin
  fm := TForm2.Create(Self);
  //fm.ManualDock(Panel1);
  fm.Show;
end;


Which version of Delphi are you using?

It is Delphi 12 Version 29.0.51511.6924

Default value for TForm.Visible property is False. This means that at the point of creation, your form is still invisible.
So when you are trying to dock the control to your form right after its creation, the form is still invisible, hence why you get the mentioned error.
Change the order of your calls to show the form first and do the docking afterwards.

That was a brilliant idea. Unfortunately it does not work. The action that sets the Active Control is triggered by a button on the newly created form, so it has to be visible so the user can press it and trigger the action , which results in the error. . I suspect that docking acts much like setting the parent of a form to another component such as the panel, at which point the error occurs.

You claim that this action is performed by a button on a newly created form and yet your code shows you are trying to do the docking from the OnClick event of the Button1 that is present on your first form.

That is correct. It is not the action of docking the newly created form that causes the error. The error occurs later when you click  a button on the newly created and visible form to set ActiveControl to some other component on the second form such as an edit box.  So at this point the new form is visible and responsive. If you do not dock the secondary form then this action completes successfully . So it seems that the action of docking causes similar issues to setting the parent of a form to be some component such as a panel
